# reading XSD from file using eclipse-mdt-xsd

Tags: xsd, eclipse-mdt

I'm trying to use the MSD-XSD library for parsing XSD files, but I can't figure out how to create an XSDSchema object from an XSD file, and if there's a way to also read the xs:include files, etc.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Include code snippets and a description of what went wrong.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I didn't see any method that seems to create an XSDSchema. XSDSchemaImpl() is private.

Comment: This is a very mature Eclipse project. There must be some documentation? Have you not got any docs or sample projects?

Comment: I got javadoc. I couldn't find and sample that reads an XSD file

Comment: Fair enough - I struggled to find the samples as well. There are some dead links in the docs. Maybe this will help: https://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-XSD-FAQ#How_can_I_load_a_XSDSchema_from_a_simple_Java_String_or_from_a_DOM_Tree.3F

Comment: Exactly.
The code you linked to doesn't compile BTW - XSDPackage.eINSTANCE.createXSDSchema() doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. Not sure if this is the easiest way.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new FileReader(file));
    Document doc = builder.parse(is);
    XSDSchema xsd = XSDSchemaImpl.createSchema(doc.getFirstChild());
```